# What is the right approach for spreading tasks to different nodes in a distributed system?

Tags: distributed, distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper, software-distribution

I'm planning a distributed system that will contain a several nodes.
What is the right approach to spread the task between the nodes?
my ideas for how to send the metadata of a task from a "master node" to a "worker node":
The "master node" is used for load balancing, I'm using zookeeper for HA, I thought about two approaches, not sure they are good:
1. creating a new znode for each task(contains task_id and metadata) and when the "master node" zookeeper watcher sees a change it moving/creating the znode to the location where the worker watcher is watching and than the worker triggers the task.
2. put the task details in DB and with a "task status", the "master node" periodically query the db and looking for "new" status, if it finds one it assign the task to a worker.
the worker also query the DB periodically and is looking for a status "assigned" with his id, then it fetches the metadata from the DB and process the task.